# Remove <![CDATA[ from WebService Response using WSO2

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wso2-data-services-server

I created a WebService using WSO2 Data Services Server, however the output/response after consuming the WebService contains the CDATA and not in the XML format I require.

This is my SQL query that produces the output in XML

```
select (select * from customerInfo
for xml path ('Customer'), type)) as CustomerInfo
```

However my output looks like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <Customer xmlns="http://test.co.za/TestCustomerInfo">
         <CustomerInfo><![CDATA[<Name>..........</Name>]]></CustomerInfo>
      </Customer>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How do I ensure the output will not contain the  tag using WSO2 Data Services Server?

All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I have worked with only RESTful and Oracle. From what I understand is that you are trying to frame an XML inside your query. But you should just select the data and let DSS frame the XML for you. If you want various levels in your XML then use nested queries feature in DSS.

Alternative if you still want to go with this approach you can write an XSLT I believe to strip out the fields you do not want and attach it in the output mapping section. But if I were you I would go for the first option.